# Which email software is used? optiext/optiextension.dll in url

Tags: windows, email, dll, newsletter

Does anybody know what email software is used by the following mailing?
It has optiext/optiextension.dll in the url. I've seen many companies are using it.

http://nieuwsbrief.ah.nl/optiext/optiextension.dll?ID=QijQmaS446wp8V4_5bBYmbqi_rNLdLq6oO5B982jqvctRCUAcRtWu_s_ROO0vnQ5YHddppLfeNw9WmBi4C3y9xEmOIddPRRsi0iGTkQy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you'll find it is part of the software stack from Selligent (www.selligent.com)

M